# Microsoft R .xdf file

Tags: r, microsoft-r

I got some question about the .xdf file:

1. What is this exacly?
2. How does this type of file work?
3. How Microsoft R works with this typ of file?
4. What are the advantages agains data.frames?

I'm really looking forward to your answers.

Greetings R123456789

Comment: Maybe read the manuals? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-r/scaler-user-guide-data-import

Comment: I read this already, but the manuals doesn't answer my question. And the questions are very important for me to understand programming with Microsoft R.

Comment: That link answers all questions, **1.** it is a compressed data file. **2,3.** using package export/import functions. **4.** Unlike dataframes it doesn't sit on the memory.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. That means, xdf-files are stored like a normal file in a folder on the SQL Server or local and data.frames "stored" in the memory? That means, that with xdf-files I got not memory limitation?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. An XDF file is a compressed binary file format with user selectable levels of compression, some quick facts can be found here: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/3104260/qa-what-is-the-.xdf-file-format XDF files come in two forms, Standalone and Composite. For Standalone XDF files, you will see a single file stored on disk with the .xdf extension. For Composite, the XDF file is represented by a directory, which contains metadata and data subdirectories. Also, for Composite, Metadata and Data files in there directories are split and individually compress as XDF part files.

---

2. It is a proprietary implementation inside of Microsoft R Server, I can expand on this answer, but i would need to refine the question, "How does this type of file work?"

---

3. An XDF file is stored on the disk and does not sit in memory. Microsoft R Server, with a call to RxXdfData() or rxImport(), will read the XDF file and decompress it, then insert it into memory as a Data Frame. Many Microsoft R "rx" functions can take a path to an XDF directly as a data source or sink, and will manage reading segments into memory as required.

---

4. The advantages of using XDF as a Data Source/Sink is that you do not need to buffer the entire file into memory for Microsoft R Server to work with it. It allows for partial reads and writes, as well as other optimizations around disk space via compression. It will operate faster than reading/writing from flat files as Metadata is used to index the XDF. The disadvantages are primarily performance, Data in-memory (data.frames) will be faster to operate on than data on disk in all cases.

---

Note: As with all files, the underlying operation system controls when a file is written from memory to disk. For the purpose of your question, the assumption can be made that the XDF file resides on disk as a standard file.

Comment: when using a data source like RxOdbc or RxSqlServerData, and passing this directly to a function like rxLinMod or rxLogit, is this creating an XDF file "in memory" and passing it directly to other functions? What's the right mental model for data movement and performance?

Comment: This does not create an XDF in memory, as in it's nature, an XDF is compressed and reserved for storage on disk. When creating a remote context data object, and then calling an algorithm on that object, rows of data are read from the data source as requested by the algorithm and are held in memory as C++ objects to be operated on. These intermediary object are proprietary to Microsoft R Server. This memory is owned by the process "BxlServer", the MRS worker process. It is not abstracted as a data type in R. Mid-operation, this intermediary data is inaccessible from the R Client.

Comment: This means that the R Server execute only the data which is requested by the algorithm and stores it in memory. And after the operation the memory would be delete or saved on disk for following algorithms, which needs the data, too?

Comment: The details of implementation are a little more complicated than that, but, if you monitor your revoJobs directories while the job is running, you will see .iro files generated. These are intermediary result output files, and these will be merged to form a result. The whole paradigm behind R server is to keep minimal data in memory so that your algorithm can run efficiently on data which is too large to fit in memory simultaneously. But the high level design is exactly as you described, memory is either freed or cached to disk when an intermediary result is formed.